# AX 2009 : TaxReporting report make AOS crash

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

In the `TaxReporting` report, there is a method called `printUndeclaredTaxPeriods`, code below:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method will retrieve if there are any transactions that happened outside
/// the date range specified for the report.
/// </summary>
void printUndeclaredTaxPeriods()
{

    TaxReportPeriod     taxReportPeriod;
    TaxTrans            taxTrans_local;
    ;

    while select taxReportPeriod
    where taxReportPeriod.FromDate < fromDate
    exists join taxTrans_local
        where taxTrans_local.TransDate      >= taxReportPeriod.FromDate
        &&    taxTrans_local.TransDate      <= taxReportPeriod.ToDate
        &&    taxTrans_local.TaxPeriod      == taxReportPeriod.TaxPeriod
        &&    taxTrans_local.TaxRepCounter  == taxReportPeriod.VersionNum
    {        
         //element.send(taxReportPeriod);          
    }
}
```

Everytime this report run, AOS crash.

When I debugged I found that line I commented causing crash.

How can I avoid this process or maybe any explanation for this case so I know what should I do for AOS crash?

Comment: What Hotfix version are you on? I do not have this problem and there is a SYP layer on the report object. I am currently running Hotfix rollup 7.

Comment: Im not sure, while im not the person who install. I can see at media installation, there are DynamicsAX2009-KB956568 and SP 1 package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any customization to the report?

Then start by removing that.

Otherwise move the fields form the `TaxReportPeriodTrans` body to a programmable section.
The move back one at a time until it crash.

Comment: Nope, there is no customization at all. Im not quite sure what your point, is that mean i got to find object for that method in the body and move it to prog. section ?

Comment: No. Move the report controls (report fields) or delete them.

Comment: Excellent ! I delete section taxReportPeriod and all its child, from method to object and last step i uncommented line at printUndeclaredTaxPeriods(). Recompile, rerun the report and its work.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue is solved in hotfix rollup 2 for AX 2009, or in the independent knowledge base article [KB 969478](https://mbs2.microsoft.com/Knowledgebase/KBDisplay.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;969478).
>
> Changing the menu item \Menu Items\Output\TaxReporting to run on client rather than server is a workaround.

Quotes from [here](https://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33/p/16920/30157.aspx#30157).

Comment: Thank you its just my laziness check to community forum. Should know this from first time.